# Помогите с оптимизацией кода

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Работаю над проектом и добавил кнопки для вывода табов и заметил, что у меня через чур много **addEventListener**. Мне интересно, как можно оптимизировать код, чтоб при этом не ломался функционал:

```
const filter = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.portfolio-menu'),
          items = menu.querySelectorAll('li'),
          btnAll = menu.querySelector('.all'),
          btnLovers = menu.querySelector('.lovers'),
          btnChef = menu.querySelector('.chef'),
          btnGirl = menu.querySelector('.girl'),
          btnGuy = menu.querySelector('.guy'),
          btnGrandmother = menu.querySelector('.grandmother'),
          btnGranddad = menu.querySelector('.granddad'),
          wrapper = document.querySelector('.portfolio-wrapper'),
          markAll = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.all'),
          markGirl = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.girl'),
          markLovers = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.lovers'),
          markChef = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.chef'),
          markGuy = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.guy'),
          no = document.querySelector('.portfolio-no');

    const typeFilter = (markType) => {
        markAll.forEach(mark => {
            mark.style.display = 'none';
            mark.classList.remove('animated', 'fadeIn');
        });

        no.style.display = "none";
        no.classList.remove('animated', 'fadeIn');

        if (markType) {
            markType.forEach(mark => {
                mark.style.display = 'block';
                mark.classList.add('animated', 'fadeIn');
            });
        } else {
            no.style.display = 'block';
            no.classList.add('animated', 'fadeIn');
        }
    };

    


    btnAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
        typeFilter(markAll);
    });

    btnLovers.addEventListener('click', () => {
        typeFilter(markLovers);
    });

    btnChef.addEventListener('click', () => {
        typeFilter(markChef);
    });

    btnGuy.addEventListener('click', () => {
        typeFilter(markGuy);
    });

    btnGirl.addEventListener('click', () => {
        typeFilter(markGirl);
    });

    btnGrandmother.addEventListener('click', () => {
        typeFilter();
    });

    btnGranddad.addEventListener('click', () => {
        typeFilter();
    });

    menu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let target = e.target;

        if (target && target.tagName == "LI") {
            items.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
            target.classList.add('active');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: "через чур" - через что?

Comment: Добавьте ещё hrml, css и напишите в чем заключается "функционал"

Answer (score 3):

Без html, css и описания, в чём заключается "функционал" сложно сразу что-то накидать. Но вот внизу код. Примерный. Смысл в том, чтобы одинаковым элементам назначить один и тот же класс и вешать слушателя на него. Но при этом элементам назначить **[data-атрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)** при помощи которых можно опознать тип. И на основе этих данных уже строить логику.

Скрипт можно ещё больше допилить, но без полноценной разметки, сейчас, это бессмысленно

```js
  const menu = document.querySelector('.portfolio-menu'),
        items = menu.querySelectorAll('li'),
        menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll('.menu-item'),

        wrapper = document.querySelector('.portfolio-wrapper'),
        wrapperItems = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.wrapper-item'),


    const typeFilter = (markType) => {
        wrapperItems.forEach(mark => {
            mark.style.display = 'none';
            mark.classList.remove('animated', 'fadeIn');
        });

        no.style.display = "none";
        no.classList.remove('animated', 'fadeIn');
        
        if (markType === 'no') {
            no.style.display = 'block';
            no.classList.add('animated', 'fadeIn');
        } else {
          menuItems.querySelectorAll(`[data-name="${markType}"]`).forEach(mark => {
              mark.style.display = 'block';
              mark.classList.add('animated', 'fadeIn');
          });
        }
    };
    
    menuItems.forEach(menuItem => {
        menuItem.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
            typeFilter(el.target.dataset.menuName);
        });
    });

    menu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let target = e.target;

        if (target && target.tagName == "LI") {
            items.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
            target.classList.add('active');
        }
    });
```

```css
.portfolio-menu, .portfolio-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
}

.menu-item, .wrapper-item {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-menu">portfolio-menu
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="menu-item"  data-menu-name="lovers">menu item lovers</div>
    <div class="menu-item"  data-menu-name="chef">menu item chef</div>
</div>


<div class="portfolio-wrapper">portfolio-wrapper
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="wrapper-item"  data-name="lovers">lovers</div>
    <div class="wrapper-item"  data-name="chef">chef</div>
    <div class="wrapper-item"  data-name="no">chef</div>
</div>
```